# remove a file from an old commit not pushed yet (Git Extension)

Tags: git, commit, git-extensions

I'm facing a peculiar situation here.

[image: the situation]

I must change the behavior of [4]xxxMerger.py and delete [4]xxxWriter
wich means cascading this to commit [5] [6] [7]

How can I do that?

I know that I can add file to commit with fixup, or even change them then rebase on origin.
I can change a commit message by rebasing on origin and asking for a reword on the commit.

But for this. I can't do a fixup since I'm at [7] and therefor those 2 file are renamed.
If I checkout [4] it wont' allow a fixup since I won't be on any branch.

may be this is simple, but I'm quite new to GIT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase --interactive <commit 4>` then set commit "5" as fixup and changes in it will be merged to 4, then 6 and 7 will be applied on top of it.

Comment: I need to checkout commit 4 and make the change in it before typing this command?

Comment: Nope, you do it from your current head (commit 7).

Comment: git rebase --interactive bb26554, putting f to the left of commit 5, result : cannot 'ficup' without a previous commit

Comment: Pick one commit earlier - git rebase --interactive bb26554^